# build-angular, axios, vite update loop

Tags: angular, npm

axios and vite are fighting with each other over the version of build-angular

Every time I run `npm audit fix --force`, I get the opposite message.  One of these two messages over and over again.

```
$ npm audit fix

up to date, audited 1000 packages in 5s

119 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

axios  0.8.1 - 1.5.1
Severity: moderate
Axios Cross-Site Request Forgery Vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wf5p-g6vw-rhxx
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10, which is a breaking change
node_modules/axios
  localtunnel  >=1.9.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of axios
  node_modules/localtunnel
    browser-sync  >=2.24.0-rc1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of localtunnel
    node_modules/browser-sync
      @angular-devkit/build-angular  >=17.0.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of browser-sync
      node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

4 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

```
$ npm audit fix -force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating @angular-devkit/build-angular to 16.2.10, which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN Found: @angular/compiler-cli@17.0.6
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm WARN   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"17.0.6" from @angular/localize@17.0.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular/localize
npm WARN     peer @angular/localize@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm WARN     1 more (the root project)
npm WARN   1 more (the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm WARN   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN Found: @angular/localize@17.0.6
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/localize
npm WARN   peer @angular/localize@"^17.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm WARN     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   1 more (the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional @angular/localize@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/localize@16.2.12
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/localize
npm WARN   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN Found: @angular/platform-server@17.0.6
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm WARN   @angular/platform-server@"^17.0.6" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional @angular/platform-server@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/platform-server@16.2.12
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm WARN   peerOptional @angular/platform-server@"^16.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN Found: typescript@5.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peer typescript@">=4.9.3 <5.2" from @ngtools/webpack@16.2.10
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack
npm WARN     @ngtools/webpack@"16.2.10" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@">=4.9.3 <5.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@5.1.6
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peer typescript@">=4.9.3 <5.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.10
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"16.2.10" from the root project
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin
-transform-unicode-property-regex instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plu
gin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated @wessberg/ts-evaluator@0.0.27: this package has been renamed to ts-evaluator. Please install ts-evaluator instead

added 98 packages, removed 78 packages, changed 20 packages, and audited 1020 packages in 23s

123 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

vite  4.4.0 - 4.4.11
Severity: moderate
Vite XSS vulnerability in `server.transformIndexHtml` via URL payload - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-92r3-m2mg-pj97
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.0.7, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/vite
  @angular-devkit/build-angular  16.2.0-next.0 - 17.0.0-rc.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of vite
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```